# Bypass MFA in the same browser session for multiple apps

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have two apps registered against my B2C AD with custom policies for the signIn flow.
*What I expect -*

- I visit App1 and login
- I visit App2 in the same browser session

The B2C should identify the active session based on the cookies and allow me to visit App2

What I see -

- The B2C bypasses the enter credentials page, but request for MFA.

I would like to know if this configuration is part of the custom policies/Technical profile, or a security configuration in the app-registration.

Comment: Are you using a displayControl or phoneFactor technical profile to implement MFA? Post your MFA technical profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B2C considers AAD session different from the MFA session. There are two Technical profiles.
So when the second app requests for authentication, B2C picks up the AAD session from the cookies, but gets no information of the MFA session.
To include MFA session in the AAD session use

```
<IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="SM-MFA" />
```

in your AAD technical profile.

Found a solution thread here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/69770/mfa-session-doesn39t-work-in-azure-b2c-custom-poli.html